# Adding Overall Smooth Scroll to a Website (Not for anchor links in the same page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add smooth scroll to my website. Like the one at [junglevibez.net](http://junglevibez.net/). I searched and all I could find was for anchor tags to the same page, with the HREF set to #someIdOnThePage. I am NOT looking for this. I am looking for smooth scroll overall, with the scroll wheel. Similar to the one on the website I mentioned above. If a post regarding this already exists, please help me find that post.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's nothing special about scrolling on the page you specified. Are you trying to bait SO users?

Comment: Try this plugin https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll

Comment: Demo http://simov.github.io/simplr-smoothscroll/examples/example-01.html

Comment: you can try [this](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage)

Comment: using **simplr-smoothscroll** can be good option but it behaves terrible when you use laptop's track-pad weather its *windows* OR *Mac*

Comment: -afaolek- I am not baiting users. I do not even own that site. You need to be on a PC to see the difference in it. It scrolls smoother with an ease in and out effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the way to go.

https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll

But you should be warned. People DON'T like when you scroll jack their browsing experience.

You should read more about it but there is a vocal majority that disliked using this technique.
You can read more about it on numerous blog posts. ex. http://www.sitepoint.com/scrolljacking-accessibility/ , http://blog.arronhunt.com/post/66973746030/stop-scrolljacking .

You should think really hard why you want to do this. There also a question about smartphone compatibility which can get really clunky.

Comment: Thank you so much for the right answer and the awesome feed back. I hope you have a good day, unlike for those who think I was baiting users for that website, despite the fact that I don't even own, or have any association with it. Thanks again! :)